# pandas replace under condition issue

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace values under column Severity if the value has the word (dtd), (dnp), (out indefintely), (out for season) in the string to levels(1-4)

I tried to replace using a dictionary, but it doesn't change the elements under the column

```
df['Severity'] = ""
df['Severity'] = df['Notes']
replace_dict = {'DTD':1,'DNP':2,'out indefinitely':3,'out for season':4}
df['Severity'] = df['Severity'].replace(replace_dict)
```

I am cleaning NBA injury data from season 2018-19

the frame look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvNsS.png)

Comment: `.replace()` looks at the whole value of the cell. You want `.str.replace()`.

Comment: .str.replace() doesn't seem to work. Thank you tho

Comment: Scratch that, ` df['Severity'].replace(replace_dict, regex=True)` should work.

Comment: it still doesn't change the values, i wonder if this is because there are other phrases other than condition

Comment: `df['Severity'] = df['Severity'].replace(replace_dict, regex=True)`

Comment: @QuangHoang – would replace values in the string – not replace the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

I would build a custom function then apply to the string column:

```
def replace_severity(s):
    """matches string `s` for keys in `replace_dict` returning values from `replace_dict`"""

    # define the keys + matches
    replace_dict = {'DTD':1,'DNP':2,'out indefinitely':3,'out for season':4}

    for key, value in replace_dict.items():
        if re.search(key, s, re.I):
            return value

    # if no results
    return None

# Apply this function to your column
df['Severity'] = df['Notes'].apply(replace_severity)
```